# Is it possible to return an iterator as an index?

Tags: c++, stl

For example, if I use `std::find_if` like this:

```
std::vector<Rect>::iterator it = 
  std::find_if(regions.begin(), regions.end(), find_region(x,y));
```

Can I get the index of the iterator `it` in a straightforward way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`std::distance(regions.begin(), it)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) from the `<iterator>` header file.

Answer (score 1):

[`distance( regions.begin(), it );`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/distance.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use std::distance(). Ensure you don't accidentally invalidate the iterator by modifying the vector in between, though.

Answer (score 1):

Vector iterators are random access, so you can simply use

```
it - regions.begin()
```

but std::distance works on a wider variety of iterator types.